# Mock request/response to/from external REST service

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, mockito

One of my application's methods uses `javax.ws.rs.Client` to POST a request with an XML payload to an external REST service and receive back an XML response. I then convert this response to JSON and return it to the method caller. How do I write a unit test that mocks out the external REST service, so I can focus on sending an XML payload, receiving back an XML response which is converted to JSON, so I can look for a specific property in the JSON to pass the test? I need to use Mockito testing framework.

I imagine the test method would need access to sample XML request and XML response strings (w/ hard coded values). If so, where would I store these strings which are a bit lengthy, particularly the response?

Comment: Checkout wiremock

Comment: It looks interesting, but Mockito is already adopted in the project and I am trying to keep testing framework libraries to a minimum. Can Mockito be used for my requirement?

Comment: Could you please paste some sample code, where you are calling `Client` method?